# Way to stop function from checking number

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a function that basically checks grid spaces from like `i-1` to `i+1` along with `j` since its coordinates in the `(i,j)`. However, when I go to check a grid space that hits the right or top side of the grid, it says it can't because it's out of range. My goal is to put something in the code for it to say like `if i == some_variable` then don't check it.

```
b_overlap = False
for i in range(grid_i-1, grid_i+1):
    for j in range(grid_j-1, grid_j+1):
        print("i, j = " + str(i) + ", " + str(j))
        if len(v_circle[i][j]) > 0:
            for c_iteration in v_circle[i][j]:
                if distance(c_candidate, c_iteration) < c_iteration.radius_ + c_candidate.radius_:
                    b_overlap = True
if not b_overlap:
    v_circle[grid_i][grid_j].append(c_candidate)
    print("Ball was added at (" + str(x) + ", " + str(y) + ")")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for boundaries using an `if` and skip those iterations:

```py
b_overlap = False
for i in range(grid_i-1, grid_i+1):
    for j in range(grid_j-1, grid_j+1):
        # Check for boundaries
        if i < 0 or i >= len(v_circle) or j < 0 or j >= len(v_circle[i]):
            continue

        print("i, j = " + str(i) + ", " + str(j))
        if len(v_circle[i][j]) > 0:
            for c_iteration in v_circle[i][j]:
                if distance(c_candidate, c_iteration) < c_iteration.radius_ + c_candidate.radius_:
                    b_overlap = True
if not b_overlap:
    v_circle[grid_i][grid_j].append(c_candidate)
    print("Ball was added at (" + str(x) + ", " + str(y) + ")")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `range(start, end)` includes `start` but excludes `end`. You can use `max()` and `min()` functions to make sure that you're not going out of range.

Assuming `grid_size_i` and `grid_size_j` are the maximum ranges for `i` and `j` dimensions, you can use `max(0, grid_i-1)` and `max(0, grid_j-1)`  to make sure you don't go below zero (the left and bottom edges of your grid), and `min(grid_i+1, grid_size_i)` and `min(grid_j+1, grid_size_j)` makes sure you don't go beyond your grid's size (the right and top edges).

```py
b_overlap = False
for i in range(max(0, grid_i-1), min(grid_i+1, grid_size_i)):
    for j in range(max(0, grid_j-1), min(grid_j+1, grid_size_j)):
        print("i, j = " + str(i) + ", " + str(j))
        if len(v_circle[i][j]) > 0:
            for c_iteration in v_circle[i][j]:
                if distance(c_candidate, c_iteration) < c_iteration.radius_ + c_candidate.radius_:
                    b_overlap = True
if not b_overlap:
    v_circle[grid_i][grid_j].append(c_candidate)
    print("Ball was added at (" + str(x) + ", " + str(y) + ")")
```

Alternatively, if your grid size can change during the course of the loop, you could use an approach like Blaz suggested where you check whether each index is valid as you go.